# Is os.walk() much faster after the first run due to page caching?

Tags: python, caching

I use `os.walk` to iterate over, say, 1000 files (just iteration, no process is done on these files).
The first run is slow, but subsequent runs (on the same path) are about 20 times faster.

As far as I know, `os.walk` and `os.listdir` (which is used by `os.walk`) didn't do any caching, nor the `FindFirstFile`/`FindNextFile` (which is used by `os.listdir` on my Windows platform).

So is this due to page caching or some thing else?

FYI, I'm trying to write a backup application and need to process huge number of files. If it's indeed due to page caching, then I'll need to write my own caching mechanism.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your OS does the caching here; directory lookups require disk access which is slow, so such access is heavily cached.

For example, the `ntfs.sys` driver [uses the Data Map service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742613.aspx) to cache filesystem metadata such as directory listings.

Comment: Is it this kind of caching? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364218(v=vs.85).aspx For if it is, then I'll lose the cache after reboot.

Comment: @fans656: That's about file caching. Here we have the caching of the directory structure.

Comment: @fans656: That's per-file caching; but directory metadata is cached too. It depends on the filesystem driver where that is cached, I found a reference for `ntfs.sys` for you.

Comment: @fans656: that said, I do suspect that NTFS treats metadata as another file and thus uses the same cache when reading those files; the Data Map is then used for the master record and offsets to find those files or a similar strategy.

Answer (score 4):

I realize you already got the answer to your question but it made me curious about how these kind of caches work in Linux, so I performed a little benchmark.

I created a directory with 1000 subdirectories, in each subdirectory I created 1000 files. 1000 folders and 1 million files in total.

```
seq 1000 | parallel "mkdir {} && seq 1000 | parallel touch {}/\{\}"
```

This should give `os.walk` something to work with. Next, I created a test script that just counts the number of files in a directory, recursively using `os.walk`:

```
def count_dir(path):
    count = 0
    for _, _, files in os.walk(path):
        count += len(files)
    return count
```

I ran this a couple of times¸ and ended up with an average execution time of 2.27 seconds.

Next, I ran the test again a couple of times but flushed the page cache between each execution, then again but flushed the dentry/inode cache and finally the same thing but flushed all of the above caches.

```
To free pagecache:
        echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
To free dentries and inodes:
        echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
To free pagecache, dentries and inodes:
        echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

The results:

```
            no flush  page cache  dentries/inodes  all
mean        2.27      2.56        4.24             4.80
stdev       0.052     0.055       0.127            0.108
%RSD        2.27%     2.15%       2.99%            2.26%
median      2.26      2.54        4.21             4.78
iterations  27        27          31               10
```

The benchmark was run on the `ext4` file system on a new SSD drive. Linux version is 3.17.7.

Not surprisingly, the page cache as well as the dentries/inodes cache are affecting the outcome of this benchmark a lot. I'm a little surprised, however, that flushing only the page cache makes such a big difference since it should be possible to read most of the file system metadata for these files at once, but I'm probably missing something.

I would have said that page caching doesn't do much of a difference since there would be relatively few cache misses for the page(s) that contains filesystem metadata. But my intuition seems to be wrong. Any ideas on why?